# Why is String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vbNullChar) = False?

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, char, .net-4.0

I am using 3rd party library to obtain data from a machine's variable. The data returns a string type, so after requesting data I'm validating that it is not an empty string like that:

```
Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data)
```

However, my program was failing, and I realized that when the variable in the machine was empty, the function above was returning True.

By debugging I noticed that the function in the 3rd party library returns `vbNullChar` when the variable is empty and `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vbNullChar)` evaluates to `False`, when I would expect it to evaluate to `True` as `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vbNullString)` does.

So is my only option to check as follows?

```
Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) AndAlso data <> vbNullChar
```

Comment: Because it is neither a `null` **reference** nor an empty string? It is a string that contains 1 character, the `\0` code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the two things you want to compare here are **different** "null" things.

`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` returns `true` if:

- The reference being passed to the method is `null`
- or ... every character of the non-`null` string is categorized as a Whitespace character ("every character" is true if the string has a length of 0)

In this case you're trying to pass in `Constants.vbNullChar` which is neither, it is a string which consists of 1 character, the `\0` character, which is not categorized as Whitespace.

`Constants.vbNullString`, on the other hand, is a `null`-reference, which `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` handles just fine.

---

As for how you should handle this concrete problem, I would do a replacement from `vbNullChar` to `null` (`vbNullString`) immediately after obtaining the results, so that this oddity will have to checked only one place.

Additionally, if you get back a string, does it end with this `\0` character? If so then you probably want to remove that as well.